# helpers not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm currently in the process of migrating my aspx mvc views to the razor engine but I've run into a bit of a head scratcher when it comes to my helpers.

I'm uncertain as to why but my helpers are being rendered out in text instead of as markup when I attempt to use the helper in its html extension form I get text not html.

The code for the extension is:

```
    public static string LinkButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string value, string target, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var linkButton = new TagBuilder("div");
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        linkButton.MergeAttribute("id", id);

        //-- apply the button class to the div and any other classes to the button
        linkButton.MergeAttribute("class", attributes.ContainsKey("class") ? string.Format("linkbutton {0}", attributes["class"]) : "linkbutton");

        var content = new TagBuilder("a");
        content.MergeAttribute("href", target);
        content.InnerHtml = value;

        linkButton.InnerHtml = content.ToString();
        return linkButton.ToString();
    }
```

This is a pretty simple extension and its used as follows:

```
[ul]
    @foreach (UpModule module in ViewBag.Modules)
    {
        [li]@Html.LinkButton(module.Name, module.Value, module.Target, new {@class = "landingButton"});[/li]
    }
[/ul]
```

apart from the blatently wrong html tags what is it that I've messed up?

**edit**
I should note that the incorrect markup is there as I'm unable to get the correct markup to show up in the my question and I am fully aware that it will not work.

Comment: What kind of file are you writing? I've never seen [ul] used in anything only <ul>.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be string and not MvcHtmlString?

Comment: @Antarr Byrd the markup is correct in my code I'm either broken in the head and can't get the html markup to shop up correctly or stack hates me right now

Comment: @voroninp That worked perfectly, but I'm uncertain as to why the Razor view required me to use an MvcHtmlString. Can you explain as I'm at a bit of a loss on that.

Comment: @codejam To protect agains cross-site scripting attacks (XSS) Razor encodes any string to be 'html-safe'. But when Razor sees MvcHtmlstring it does not incode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings returned in your templates by means of the `@` razor syntax are by default HTML encoded in order to not output HTML markup directly.

```
var s = "<p>text</p>";
....
@s
```

will output something similar to

```
&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;
```

In order to prevent this, you could use `HtmlHelper`s `Raw` method:

```
@Html.Raw(s)
```

Or you may use a `HtmlString` (or before .NET 4, `MvcHtmlString`):

```
var s = new HtmlString("<p>text</p>");
```

By using a `HtmlString` (`MvcHtmlString`), razor knows not to HTML-encode the output string.

---

In your particular case you therefore either use `@Html.Raw(Html.LinkButton(...))`, or you change the output type of your helper extension:

```
public static HtmlString LinkButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string value, string target, object htmlAttributes)
...
return new HtmlString(linkButton.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

@voroninp switching the return type from string to MvcHtmlString worked perfectly however, in this case using the declarative helper is a better clearer option though switching the return type for my more complex helper will work much better.